# HowTo update/modify LINQ EntitySet?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entityset

In my LINQ to SQL generated classes I have some classes containing EntitySets.

Everything looks great until I need to modify the EntitySet (add, delete some relationships).
I thought that it was going to work doing something like:

```
User.Actions = newUserActions;   //This is how I used it with NHibernate
```

Then when I try to submit changes, I may get a duplicate key exception, that means it is not clearing the old actions before assigning the new ones and some of them may be repeated; do I have to do it manually ?

What is the best way to do this (update the EntitySet) ? Suggestions?

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I have to do it manually. I mean first delete the relationships (EntitySet):

```
//The EntitySet is user.UserActions
DataBaseContext.UserActions.DeleteAllOnSubmit(user.UserActions);
DataBaseContext.SubmitChanges();
```

And after that, assign the "new" EntitySet:

```
user.UserActions.Assign(GetSelectedActions());
DataBaseContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I made it work doing that but...
DO I have to apply 2 SubmitChanges() to database? 
Isn't it a better way to do it?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is no better way to do this so we submit only the mutated part of the object tree in one submission and without manually modifying it. Maybe [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) can be used here, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be easier?

```
user.UserActions.Clear();
user.UserActions.AddRange(GetSelectedActions());
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: No man that didn't work it keeps throwing this ex: "Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use."

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL database relationships did you have cascade delete set? You need this set and the classes regenerating to resolve this.